# does this sum have a closed form formula

Tags: calculus

Suppose $f(x) = 1 + 2x + x^2 + 2 x^3 + ... $. That is, $c_n = 1$ for even $n$ and $2$ for the odd ones. How can we find the interval of convergence??

Well, $((-1)^n2 - 1 )x^n$ I tried, but nothing. Is there a way to write in a way  to use the ratio test to find $R$ ?

Comment: try f(x)=(1+x+x^2+x^3+...)+x(1+x^2+x^4+...)
both are geometric progressions

Comment: @Vlad But don't forget that you can't always reorder summands in the infinite sum. This approach gives a hypothesis which should be checked additionally, especially at interval ends.

Comment: This certainly converges for small x,since it is less than 2/(1-x). So you can rearrange it.

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Rewrite it as $\;(1+2x)(1+x^2+x^4+\dots)$.